# Postgresql skips ignoring micro seconds part of timestamp when 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a Postgresql database and create a table like this:

```
psql (9.5.6) 
mydb=> CREATE TABLE ts_fail(ts TIMESTAMP);
mydb=> INSERT INTO ts_fail VALUES (NOW()),('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000'::TIMESTAMP);
```

When selecting from this table I get:

```
mydb=> SELECT * FROM ts_fail;
             ts
----------------------------
 2018-01-10 12:08:28.624142
 2018-01-01 00:00:00
(2 rows)
```

Now in the second row the microsecond part is just cut off, I would expect 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 here. I need a common format, because I need to parse this timestamps in PHP to make DateTime objects.

I know I can do:

```
mydb=> SELECT to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') FROM ts_fail;
          to_char
----------------------------
 2018-01-10 12:08:28.624142
 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000
(2 rows)
```

But is there a way to change this behavior **globally**?

Comment: I think there's no global format for this. but would not php parse both ts? with and without trailing zeroes

Comment: No, it doesn't. PHP expects a DateTime in format ("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"). In my case, if the microsecond part is "000000" in the DB it will be empty when retrieving in PHP and date parsing will fail with `Data missing` because it expects *something*.

Comment: explicit conversion is better than to rely on server or session settings, seems there is a DateStyle session setting but it doesn't handle this setting

Comment: Well, I don't want to convert data. I put "2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000", it is stored with that precision and I expect it to come out again. Imo losing precision here is a bug.

Comment: it does not loose it - it does not show obvious zeros - no?..

Comment: It looses it on output. I think this is strange behavior and even more strange that it apparently cannot be changed.

Comment: Any format you see is applied by the application _displaying_ the values. I am not sure if you can configure `psql` to automatically show all timestamp values in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I found out PHP supports a "+" modifier in DateFormat, which matches trailing data. So in my case the micro seconds, if they exist (are not 0000000).

Another problem of the laravel framework was, that it uses the same dateFormat for input and output. When outputting a format with "+" in it however, a literal "+" character is included. To prevent this behavior I split the date format in `$inputFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s+"` and `$outputFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s"` and overwrote the `asDateTime()` function in Laravel.

The only disadvantage is, that I now really lose this precision. But it doesn't really matter for my application.